# how to iterate large dataset with thousands of features and modify their name

Tags: python, pandas

I am writing a Python function with pandas for cleaning a large dataset with thousands of features. Here is my code:

def cleandata(dataset):

```
for element in dataset.columns:
    typ=str(dataset[element].dtype)[:3]
    print(typ)
    if (typ=='flo') or (typ=='int'):
        dataset[element]=dataset.element.interpolate(method='values')
        scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
        dataset[element+'_scaled'] = scaler.fit_transform(dataset[element])
        del dataset[element]
    else:
        dataset[element][dataset.element.isnull()] = 'unknown'
        dataset['new_'+element] = dataset[element].map( lambda x : re.compile("([a-zA-Z]+)").search(x).group())
        dataset['new_'+element] = pd.factorize(dataset['new_'+element])[0]
        del dataset[element]
return dataset
```

The purpose is to iterate each column in this csv file (containing data) and based on the feature's type, doing corresponding normalization and replace the old column with this final result and change column name.

Then I type: cleandata(train_data).head()

I got such error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'element'

May I ask for help about this?

Appreciate!

Comment: Have you tried debugging your script by, e.g., printing `element` and its type (on the second line)? That may show you what is wrong.

Comment: You;re trying to access your column as an attribute: `dataset.element.` this won't work use `dataset[element]` instead in your code

Comment: Your type-checking is horrendously convoluted. `if isinstance(dataset[element].dtype, (float, int)):` can do all that in one line.

Comment: Also you can filter your df into numeric and non-numeric types by doing `dataset.select_dtypes([np.number])` and `dataset.select_dtypes([np.object])`

Answer (score 2):

Your error is that you're trying to use a variable as an attribute to access your column, if you passed it as a list element then it would work:

```
In [16]:
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('abcd'))
df

Out[16]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c, d]
Index: []

In [18]:
for col in df.columns:
    print(df.col)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-19c2cded2fac> in <module>()
      1 for col in df.columns:
----> 2     df.col

C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.1\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   2358                 return self[name]
   2359             raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" %
-> 2360                                  (type(self).__name__, name))
   2361 
   2362     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'col'
```

compare with:

```
In [19]:
for col in df.columns:
    print(df[col])

Series([], Name: a, dtype: object)
Series([], Name: b, dtype: object)
Series([], Name: c, dtype: object)
Series([], Name: d, dtype: object)
```

Note that I strongly advise you **always** access your columns using square brackets, accessing columns as attributes can lead to erroneous and ambiguous behaviour

Comment: That is very helpful!! Thanks a lot to your help!

Comment: A follow up for this set of code: after I edit the attribute problem, it seems one more error comes;                                                                                                ---> 14             dataset[element] = dataset[element].map( lambda x : re.compile("([a-zA-Z]+)").search(x).group())
     15             dataset[element] = pd.factorize(dataset[element])[0]
     16             scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()

TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object